# Spring Validating Controller with @Validated

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have an object like so:

```
public class Foo {
  public interface FooValidator{};

  @Null(groups = {FooValidator.class}, message = "Id is null!!!")
  private Integer id;

  @NotEmpty(message = "Description is empty")
  private String description;
}
```

And a controller like so:

```
public class FooController {
  @PutMapping(value = "/{actionItemId}")
  public ResponseEntity bar1(@Validated({Foo.FooValidator.class}) @RequestBody Foo foo) {
      //stuff
  }

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity bar2(@Validated @RequestBody Foo foo) {
      //stuff
  }
}
```

My problem is for the `bar1` method, it's only validating the `id` field and not the description field. But the `bar2` method is working fine, it's validating the description field and not the id field.

How do I get spring's `@Validated` annotation to validate fields with the appropriate interface annotation AND all the other normal fields (one's without annotation.

In other words, how do i get the `bar1` method to validate both the `id` and the `description` fields?

Answer (score 9):

`@Validated` annotation should be used on class level. It is used to say that inside the class some validation is performed. Meaning that it works with other validation annotation which will be applied to properties, parameters etc. I am posting an example from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-validation.html):

```
@Service
@Validated
public class MyBean {

    public Archive findByCodeAndAuthor(@Size(min = 8, max = 10) String code,
            Author author) {
        ...
    }

}
```

If you want to validate a custom class, as it seems to me from the example, you should instead use the `@Valid` [annotation](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) which will apply validation to the properties of the class.

Comment: "example from the documentation" You could add the link in your post. It would make it still better.

Comment: @davidxxx Added.

Comment: What if the code contains special character? if I send abc@12345, it will send me an error. Is there any way to validate only after decoding the URL.